# SQL Server: Concat Rows / or Columns and update result to Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, rows, concatenation

Following Situation:

I have a dynamically (by columns) builded table ... eg:

```
 Rowid UniqueID Name Birthdate Town ....
   1     null    Joe  Jan-93    Cologne
   2     null    Nick Okt-00    London
```

I am building this TempTable to create an uniqueID for all Data in my DataBase
The TempTable was created by two loops which run through all my DataBase Table & Columns and copy all primary key Data to this TempTable.

My aim is to update the UniqueID Column from my TempTable with the concat values of data ... eg:

```
    UniqueID
  JoeJan-93Cologne
  NickOkt-00London
```

Do you have an idea how to update UniqueID ?

What I m thinking about is:

```
Loop 1 going through all Tables
 Select Table of Schema
Loop 2 going through all Columns of Table
 Select Column of Schema

 Copy Column to my Temp 

 -- here an update  like ... set UniqueID = select concat(UniqueID, @Column) 
 -- from @table where RowID = RowID
End loop 2 
end loop 1
```

Is this possible 
Or do I have to open a third loop which is running through all rows and concat values ?

Comment: This screams of being an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you think that every row in every table needs to have a database wide unique value? This has a very strong code smell to it.

Comment: I am writing  a script to compare xxx of "equal" db schemas but do not have any unique values ... so I built some (... I m not so happy with except and intersect)

Comment: You are trying to compare schemas or the data in the tables? Seems like a cross database query would be about a zillion times simpler if comparing data.

Comment: @SeanLange : My problem is , I need to compare thousands of tables and schema ... What kind of idea do you have ( I am not that pro developer )

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to compare. Are the tables structures identical on both databases? Are you wanting all data from either database that is not in the other one?

Comment: @SeanLange I m trying to compare two schema which should be equal but it is suspected that some data missing. The problem is, one schema was imported really poorly (no meta data) to database ... sometimes columns are missing ... data formats are different ...

Comment: So you are trying to compare both schema and data. OK. Doing this yourself is going to be painful!!! This is something I would use a third party app for. One such app would be SqlCompare from redgate. There are several others also.

Comment: SqlCompare... Thx ! I ll check this out (but i m afraid that 3rd party software is not allowed or take too long to use ...)

Comment: Take too long to use??? It is a heck of a lot faster than posting a question on SO, waiting for responses and then spending a few days writing a solution. :) Good luck my friend, this type of querying is not easy to do, especially for comparing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
Update <YourTableName>
set UniqueId = ISNULL(Name, '') +  ISNULL(Cast(Birthdate as Varchar(10), '') + ISNULL(Town, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONCAT()` with `UPDATE` statement, no any loop required :

```
UPDATE t
     SET UniqueID = CONCAT(Name, Birthdate, Town);
```